# Modificar la tabla User

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Veran, tengo la tabla User, que es la que almacena a los usuarios de mi base de datos.
Estoy interesado en añadir una variable saldo, para que pueda dicho usuario hacer compras online.
Estoy viendo 2 opciones:
-La primera es modificar User.php para añadir una variable de saldo. Esta tabla no tiene una migración como las demas, de ahi a mi pregunta.
-La otra opción es crear una tabla para targetas de credito, con saldo y claves foranea a un usuario.

La cuestión es, ¿como introduzco migraciones a la tabla User?

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada no entiendo por qué dices que la tabla Users no tiene una migración, si de hecho es la primera de dos migraciones que incluye por defecto Laravel:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php

---

A continuación, si quieres hacer modificaciones a la tabla User, simplemente sigue la documentación de migraciones al respecto, incluso tienes un ejemplo directamente con la tabla Users:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#columns

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('saldo');
});
```

Comment: Cierto, por fin he encontrado la migración. Lo que si es que me es extraño eso de poner las nuevas variables en Schema::table en vez de en el Schema::create. ¿Hay alguna diferencia?

Comment: Schema::table es para modificaciones en una tabla existente, Schema::create es cuando la tabla no existe y la vamos a crear.

Comment: Adivino, si la migración la hago poniendo las novedades en create se borra lo que hubiese antes al poner php artisan migrate:fresh, pero con table se conserva los datos antigüos. ¿Cierto?

Comment: No realmente, la creación en teoría se hace una sola vez, nunca lo he intentado porque no es coherente, básicamente estás escribiendo dos veces `CREATE TABLE bla ...`, lo cual generará un error la segunda vez que lo ejecutes (ya fue creada la tabla). Con Schema::table todo "se conserva".

Comment: Pues he probado como tu dices y me da error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Schema' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Comment: Tambien he probado del otro modo. Ese si que modifica la tabla correctamente, pero ahora me da los fallos al intentar registrar el usuario (no aparece el saldo entre las variables).

Comment: ¿cuál es el otro método? Si te da ese error es porque no estás siguiendo la documentación o lo estás poniendo en el lugar incorrecto.

Comment: con el otro metodo me refiero a ponerlo en Schema::create.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73255/discussion-between-miguel-alparez-and-shaz).

Comment: tengo entendido que cuando usas php artisan migrate:fresh se borra previamente las tablas. A ver si encuentro como modificar el formulario de los usuarios.

Comment: Sí se borra, pero una cosa es hacer las migraciones de nuevo, y otra hacer dos veces la creación de una tabla. Tal vez no estás explicando bien lo que pretendes hacer.

Comment: Lo que quiero es darle a la tabla User una variable de saldo para que el usuario pueda hacer compras. Si por el camino se borra lo que tuviera me da igual porque esto es solo una practica.

Comment: Realmente depende de como esté hecho (pensado) el proyecto. Si decides usar las migraciones que trae Laravel por defecto o no. Puedes modificar la sintaxis de la creación de la tabla para agregar el campo en esa, o puedes simplemente agregar el campo posteriormente, en una modificación en otra migración. A lo largo de las preguntas que has hecho hemos visto que al parecer no lees la documentación o no la sigues correctamente y por eso creería que no entiendes los conceptos básicos y cometes errores extremadamente elementales que se resuelven con una búsqueda en Google o con la documentación.

Comment: ya he creado la variable saldo en la tabla de usuarios. Por ahora empieza siendo nulo, pero posteriormente le daremos valor con un formulario. Ahora bien ¿Como accedo a los datos del usuario que actualmente tiene la sesión activa? Conozco cosas como @Logged(), que comprueba si hay alguien tiene su sesión activa, pero no se en caso afirmativo como acceder a parametros como su nombre, email o en mi caso, su saldo.

Comment: en añadido, he descubierto que con auth() puedo acceder al usuario y puedo por ejemplo poner auth()->id() para acceder a su codigo. Sin embargo, no tengo acceso al saldo. No hay un metodo saldo() y si intento poner auth()->saldo me sale esto: Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$saldo

Comment: Arreglado. Es cuestión de utilizar esto: Auth::user()->saldo